# How to copy every repository/folder from one JFrog artifactory to another JFrog artifactory using Python?

Tags: python, artifactory

There is a package called "dohq-artifactory" in python which copies **file** from one to another artifactory but not folders/repositories. I have tried to copy folder with same package but It didn't work.

Please let me know how to accomplish this with python or suggest if there is any better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanism to copy artifacts between 2 different Artifactory instances is replication (or [repository import/export](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Import+and+Export#ImportandExport-RepositoriesImportandExport) , however this will import the entire repository and will override existing content in the target which is not the case here).

You can configure [push replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Replication#RepositoryReplication-PushReplication) between the 2 repositories to replicate artifacts. As you want to replicate only a single specific file, you can configure the Path prefix with the path to that artifact.

[image]
With the Path Prefix configured, only artifacts under that path will be replicated to the target repository. After the replication has completed and the file was deployed to the target repository, you can delete the replication configured.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sunny. Is there any way to accomplish this using python? Because I want to transfer many folders/repositories from one to another artifactory. So, If I can write a script to automate this then it would make my job easier.

Comment: Hi Eswar, you can make use of Artifactory REST API https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API

Pull/Push Replication:https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Pull/PushReplication


Set Repository Replication Configuration
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetRepositoryReplicationConfiguration

Comment: One more doubt about uploading artifacts, I'm trying to upload 5 GB package to artifactory through python package. Since it is too big, its taking time to upload and after sometime connection is getting closed due to which uploading is failing. Any suggestions or references on this.

Comment: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact

Comment: Hi Sunny, Is there a way on how to upload existing python packages(i.e., pytest, flask, sklearn etc...) to artifactory? Like downloading from pypi and upload it to private artifactory